# glibc detect smallbin linked list corrupted

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to run a function repeatedly in a large loop but I get an error after 2 or 3 iterations but if I start from the point it gave an error it works fine but again stops after 3 4 iteration. It might be a memory problem. As the function is quite large I am not sure where exactly there is a memory leakage. Is there anyway I can free the variables after each iteration or something that can solve this problem. Or as it is a linked list memory problem free all the linked list or something?What can be the solution? The problrm does not happen if I run the function once so I think it is because I am calling the function repeatedly in a loop. Is there any way to solve this problem?

The error is

```
**glibc detected:.....malloc():smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x000000000 1d404c0 ***
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The library is telling you that the memory metadata is corrupt. That won't happen by mere memory leak, you had to write to invalid pointer. Either you wrote to index out of bounds or you wrote to pointer after it was freed.

The easiest way to debug this kind of issue is using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It only works under Linux, but you seem to be using that already. It is rather slow, because it single-steps the program and checks every memory-accessing instruction, but it can catch invalid memory access and also use of uninitialized variables and memory leaks very reliably.

There is also [duma (detect unintended memory access)](http://duma.sourceforge.net/) library. It can also be made to work on other platforms and is a bit faster, but it uses much more memory.

And there is gcc's own [mudflap](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Mudflap_Pointer_Debugging) that can be activated by specific compiler options. That one should work on most gcc targets, but I am not sure how complete the C++ support is.

Update (11/2018): mudflap is mostly superseded by [Google Sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers), which are part of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html).

Comment: I am getting the same error in different part of my program so I can't figure where the error is I will try to use valgrind.Thanks.

Comment: @user1583647: The corruption is usually pseudo-random and standard library only detects it long after it actually happened. But valgrind can catch when the invalid access happens.

Comment: is there any way to get the memory leaks or memory problems of the program apart from the standard library of the program?

Comment: @user1583647: Now I really don't know what you mean.

Comment: I ran the valgrind but it gives me a long long list of errors most of them are from the standard library used in the program so is there any way to just list the memory leaks in my program apart from the standard library used?

Comment: @user1583647: The last frame is standard library, but they are almost certainly caused by your incorrect use of the library. You have to analyse the backtraces.

Comment: For modern versions of gcc (>= 4.9), Mudflap's own documentation directs one to use [google/sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers) instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Very specific use case**

I had this problem within an application written with Qt where I was using pointers to an object derived from `QObject` that had a copy constructor.  I somehow overlooked the following warning during compilation:

```
warning: base class ‘class QObject’ should be explicitly initialized in the copy constructor [-Wextra]
```

It turns out that `QObject`-derived objects [are not supposed to be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19092698/1525238), but I did not expect the copy constructor on my `QObject`-derived class to cause this kind of error.