# can I reuse the QPainter?

Tags: c++, image, qt

Rendering to bitmap, I have to create a QPainter.  If I have to render multiple areas to multiple bitmaps, how do I reset the QPainter ?

```
QImage img1(scene1.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img1.fill(Qt::color0);
QPainter painter1(&img1);
painter1.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene1.render(&painter1);
painter1.end();

QImage img2(scene2.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img2.fill(Qt::color0);
QPainter painter2(&img2);
painter2.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene2.render(&painter2);
painter2.end();
```

How can I reuse the painter ? am I getting performance hits/higher memory usage by creating a new QPainter for each scene / image ?

Trying

```
QImage img(scene1.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img.fill(Qt::color0);
QPainter painter(&img);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene1.render(&painter);
painter.end();
img.save("img.png");

img = QImage(scene2.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img.fill(Qt::color0);
painter = QPainter(&img);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene2.render(&painter);
painter.end();
```

I get errors of the type

```
error: 'QPainter& QPainter::operator=(const QPainter&)' is private
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse your `QPainter` with the following syntax:

```
QPainter painter;

painter.begin( &img1 );
...
painter.begin( &img2 );
...
```

But you can only use one `QPainter` for one `QPaintDevice` (in this case an image).

[Read this.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#begin)

Comment: If I reuse the same QImage, it is ok to reuse the painter then ? I have just modified the code to use pointer, that seemed to work too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that QObject and Classes derived from it, as well as QPainter and maybe other classes, have private constructors (??? why)

So...

```
QImage img(scene1.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img.fill(Qt::color0);
QPainter* painter = new QPainter(&img);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene1.render(painter);
painter->end();
img.save("img.png");

img = QImage(scene2.sceneRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
img.fill(Qt::color0);
painter = new QPainter(&img);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
scene2.render(painter);
painter->end();

delete painter;
```

I was writing this as vizhanyolajos was posting his answer, and I think I prefer that answer.

Comment: [See this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator) for info about why `QObject` has a private copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: thanks - QPainter does not inherit or extend QObject but it seems it has the same design, which is why it seems easier to use the approach above, even though in all Qt examples I see it being used as normal object (not pointer) - with the minor advantage of having Qt deal with cleanup. I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you are doing it like you have it in this code snippet, you have a memory leak. You create two `QPainter` instances but you only delete one.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need to write this:

QPainter* painter = new QPainter( &img );

you can write this instead:

QPainter painter( &img );

with this you don't have to think about the deleting of the obejct.

Yes, all the QObject derived classes have private copy constructors. [You can read about the reasons here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092513/copy-constructor-of-derived-qt-class)

Comment: This is how I have it in the question, but if it is not a pointer then it is not reusable - except in the way you mentioned in your other answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to worry about the reusing of the QImage. You can instantiate a new instance and use the being( ... ) function of the QPainter class.

Comment: :-) as my code shows in both question and my own answer, QImage reusing is not a problem. And  do not need a new instance. I have memory problems, the images are very large, so i CAN'T create new QImage instance - I HAVE TO reuse

Comment: btw no need to post separate answer - you can comment on existing one