# How to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE on QGraphicsitem derived class?

Tags: qt, copy-constructor, qgraphicsitem

I want to use my objects as QVariants and for queued connections. Therefore I want to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(My_Item) and from the documentation I learned that I need a public copy constructor. I tried to write one, but I failed. Than I did read this [copy constructor of derived QT class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092513/copy-constructor-of-derived-qt-class) and the answer by BЈовић. From there I understand that what I intended to do is not going to work. What do I have to do make my objects useable for the Metatypesystem?

My_Item is based on My_Super_Item, which look like this:

```
class My_Item: public My_Super_Item {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
   explicit My_Item(Application *a, QString astring);
...
}
```

and

```
class My_Super_Item : public QObject, public virtual QGraphicsItem {
 Q_OBJECT 
 Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
 My_Super_Item(My_Application *a, QString astring);
 ...
}
```

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: @thuga :  updated the question, in general I want to learn how to use these features

Comment: You cannot copy `QObjects`. Why do you want to put them in `QVariant` anyway? You don't need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` for queued connections.

Comment: I understood that I have to use Q_DECLARE_METATYPE for own objects when using signals between threads. And that QVariant is a method for putting different objects into a list together.

Comment: What other object types you have in this list? For queued connections you need [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

Comment: @thuga : other types, like QColor, QString or numbers via QVariant

Comment: Why do you store all this in a list? Doesn't seem like a list to me.

Comment: I know that there are other (better) ways of doing it, still I am interessted in how to solve it

Comment: You can store pointers in `QVariant`.

Comment: Yes, but this will not work between threads

Comment: Well in case of `QGraphicsItem`s, they are not thread safe / reentrant, so you shouldn't use them in different threads.

Comment: Yes, I know, I have to add my own locking unless I just want to read them

Comment: No, you should not use them in a different thread at all. Unless you're just accessing your own data members, but then you should just pass those to the other thread.