# qt give an ui component to an object function

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I want to create an object function that changes the color of a certain pushbutton. I would like to give an ui->pushbutton to it.

So I would be calling the function with something like this:

```
changeButtonColor(ui->pushbutton);
```

How do I need to write the function?

```
void MainWindow::changeButtonColor(ui->pushbutton)
{
}
```

Comment: what is your question? do you know how to define a function that takes eg an `int` as parameter?

Comment: This code is not legal C++. A method definition expects a type, not an object.

Comment: You may need to read or revisit a basic C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the pushbutton in the function you have two options to pass it as an argument to a function: as a pointer, or as a reference. In each case, the function signature (prototype) would be:

*Pointer parameter:*

```
void MainWindow::changeButtonColor(QPushButton * button);
```

*Reference parameter:*

```
void MainWindow::changeButtonColor(QPushButton & button);
```

In each case, a call to the function would be:

*Pointer argument:*

```
changeButtonColor(ui->pushbutton);
```

*Reference argument:*

```
changeButtonColor(*ui->pushbutton);
```

More information: [difference between a pointer and reference parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620604/difference-between-a-pointer-and-reference-parameter)

Comment: how about passing values?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 if you could pass a pushbutton by value to a function, then you could not change the button color with this function.

Comment: A more general explanation to the question why you can't pass a pushbutton object by value to a function is that all QWidgets derive from QObject, which has the copy constructor and assignment operator disabled. [More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092513/copy-constructor-of-derived-qt-class).

Comment: might be true for pushbuttons and this question, but you start with "In C++, you have two options to pass an object as an argument to a function:"

Comment: Fixed the answer to delimit the scope. I've also edited the question to improve its inteligibility (pending of peer review)

Comment: made an edit. Its just a suggestion....